# How to prove that $\overline{\Bbb H^1} \times \overline{\Bbb H^1} \cong \overline{\Bbb H^2}$?

Tags: general-topology

Let  $\overline{\Bbb H^n} = \{(x^1, ..., x^n) \in \Bbb R^n \mid x^n \geq 0\}$, equipped with the usual subspace topology of $\Bbb R^n$.

I'm trying to prove that $\overline{\Bbb H^1} \times \overline{\Bbb H^1}$ is homeomorphic to $\overline{\Bbb H^2}$.

I can see it "visually" (it's like opening a book) but I don't know how to find an explicit map...

Comment: Hint: Use the polar coordinates, then there is a verify simple formula describing such a homeomorphism.

Comment: @MoisheCohen What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: @JohnB: Did I say that I do not understand something?

Comment: That's simply obvious. :)

Comment: @JohnB: It depends on how much topology one knows. In a research paper I would not bother writing a proof of this staement, but if somebody just learned the definition of a topological space, things might be not as obvious. Not that it applies in this case, but for many people the Jordan curve theorem is "obvious", until they are asked to write a proof...

Comment: What is H1??.??

Comment: @WilliamElliot Presumably, it is the half-space $\mathbb H^1 = \{ x \in \mathbb R \mid x > 0 \}$.

Comment: The line at infinity is missing a point at infinity! I suggest defining $\overline{\mathbb H^n}$ by the disk/ball model instead. Then you're proving that a line segment times a line segment is a disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So we are actually trying to show $[0, +\infty\rangle \times [0, +\infty\rangle \cong \mathbb{R} \times [0, +\infty\rangle$.

As @Moishe Coher suggests, you can use polar coordinates. Notice that:

$$[0, +\infty\rangle \times [0, +\infty\rangle = \left\{(r,\phi) : r \ge 0, \phi\in \left[0, \frac\pi2\right]\right\}$$
$$\mathbb{R} \times [0, +\infty\rangle = \left\{(r,\phi) : r \ge 0, \phi\in \left[0, \pi\right]\right\}$$

Obviously we should consider the map $f : [0, +\infty\rangle \times [0, +\infty\rangle \to \mathbb{R} \times [0, +\infty\rangle$ given by $$(r,\phi) \stackrel{f}{\mapsto} (r,2\phi)$$ It is indeed a homeomorphism of the two spaces.

---

You can express $f$ explicitly in Cartesian coordinates. After a bit of computation we arrive at the formula:

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\left(x^2-y^2, 2xy\right),  & \text{if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$} \\
(0,0), & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$}
\end{cases}$$

$f$ is obviously continuous for $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$. To verify continuity of $(0,0)$ note that

$$\|f(x,y)\|^2 = \frac{(x^2-y^2)+4x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} = x^2 + y^2 = \|(x,y)\|^2$$

The inverse function is given explicitly as:

$$f^{-1}(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\left( w(x,y), \frac{-2x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}w(x,y) + w(x,y)^{3}}{y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right),  & \text{if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$} \\
(0,0), & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$}
\end{cases}$$

where $w(x,y) = \sqrt{x\sqrt{x^2+y^2} + x^2 + y^2}$.

Again, continuity of  $f^{-1}$ at $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ is evident from the formula, while continuity at $(0,0)$ follows from $\|f^{-1}(x,y)\| = \|(x,y)\|$.

We conclude that $f$ is a homeomorphism.